# Broadcast message from server to specific client outside of a hub

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a Web API project which has a SignalR hub in it to send messages to specific clients (in a separate MVC App). Sending to all clients works fine but sending to a specific one has been a challenge. How can I change my code in order to accomplish this? Below is my current set up.

Hub Class (read elsewhere it's possible to associate each user to a single group)

```
[HubName("GWEventHub")]
public class GatewayEventHub : Hub
{        
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, this.Context.Request.User.Identity.Name);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    // No other methods needed as client does not need to message the server

}
```

Code in API controller which sends message to client

```
private void SendClientMessage(string message)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GatewayEventHub>();
    context.Clients.All.sendClientMessage(message);
}
```

Client Code

```
$(function () {

    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:53453/signalr";
    var hub = $.connection.GWEventHub;

    hub.client.sendClientMessage = function(message) {
        console.log("message recieved from GW service " + message);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('connect to GatewayEventHub, Connection ID = ' + $.connection.hub.id);
    })
    .fail(function (e) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to signalr hub at ' + hub.url + 'Connection Error: ' + e);
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried `context.Clients.Client(connectionId)` or `context.Clients.User(userId)` ?

Comment: @Pawel  how would my api controller have access to the connectionID in order to pass it in when that is called from outside the hub?

Comment: That's just something you have to know, Stavros_S. There's no way around it. Just store your `connectionId/userId` somewhere your api has access to it.

Comment: @Buildstarted if I can't store it in a db at the moment then what sort of object am I able to share between the hub class and an api controller? I don't think a singleton would work since the connectionId will change for every client so the state would be lost.

Comment: You could create a static dictionary or something and update it when the client connects or disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a ChatRoom (If its a chat you are doing) class that holds all connected userid's or connectionids depending on if you want the Chat room to be global for each connected user (UserId) or if you want the ChatRoom to be unique for each browser tab (connection id).

When you connect to a chat room add the user/conn.id to the chatroom instance. You can make sure that users are disposed of if you override OnDisconnect in the hub and remove the user from all chatrooms were he is active.

Comment: I'm actually just broadcasting server messages to clients, so it's not really going to be two way communication but I see your idea hear and can probably make it work in a similar fashion to what I need.